# writing variables to the sheet PHP

Tags: php, post, input

Iam staring with PHP. I'm trying to enter data into the website, make some calculations, and write it on website

```
<p><input type="number" id="a" > Typa A value </input>  </p>
<p><input type="number" id="b" > Type B value   </input>  </p>
<p><input type="submit" id="c" value="c " > </button>
```

```
session_start(); 
if (isset($_POST['a'])) {      

$a=$_POST['a'];
$a=$_POST['b'];
$d= $a * $b 
echo $d; }
```

//how to type it on website?

Comment: `<input>` is self-closing, that meaning it does not have a `</input>` tag. Also, you need `name` attributes to actually send data

Comment: To use the form inputs in php you must use NAME and not ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't confuse to declare variables.

First **change your html to this:**

```
<p><input type="number" name="a" > Typa A value </input>  </p>
<p><input type="number" name="b" > Type B value   </input>  </p>
<p><input type="submit" name ="c"> </button>
```

**Change your php code to this:**

```
  session_start(); 
if (isset($_POST['c'])) {      

$a=$_POST['a'];
$b=$_POST['b'];
$d= (int)$a * (int)$b;  

echo $d;
}
```

It is in simplest way.

Comment: Problem was a  ' id="a"   ' in my code. You have right with  ' name="a" '

Comment: In html  `<form>` add `action="filename itself"`